# Webpack not creating submodules in the library namespace

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to build a Webpack config allowing me to create multiple modules in a specific namespace. I have a the following config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'one': './src/modules/one/one.module.js',
        'two': './src/modules/two/two.module.js',
        'three': './src/modules/three/three.module.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].module.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: ['myModules', '[name]'],
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    ...
};
```

The problem is, that it creates a global namespace: `myModules`, but the submodules are not visible. I'm not able to create a new instance by running `new window.myModules.one();`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using ES modules and that you have a default export for each module, you would have to access the `default` property.

```
new window.myModules.one.default();
```

Webpack 3 added the [`output.libraryExport`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-libraryexport) option, which allows you to assign a specific export to the library target. Instead of having an object with the exports, you could have just the default export in place. For this you need to set `output.libraryExport` to `'default'`.

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].module.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: ['myModules', '[name]'],
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default',
},
```

With that you can use it as you've wanted.

```
new window.myModules.one();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The `libraryExport: 'default',` was the missing piece!